# Copying image from a worksheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a Python program that creates a new excel file based on some worksheets from a few other files. The following code I have copies the worksheets perfectly, but is unable to copy the image that is present in the worksheet. How do I copy images in an Excel worksheet to another Excel workbook using Python?

```
path1 = "/mnt/e/RecEasy-MVP-Python/FlaskApp/Uploaded_files/" + key
print path1
path2 = "/mnt/e/RecEasy-MVP-Python/FlaskApp/Compiled/"  + current_acc_group + "_" + current_gl_account + ".xlsx"
print path2
path_to_key_sheet = "/mnt/e/RecEasy-MVP-Python/FlaskApp/Uploaded_files/" + key + "_key_sheet.txt"
print "Path to key sheet file:"
print path_to_key_sheet

wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1, read_only=True, data_only=True)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[2]
counter = 0
for sheet in wb1:
   if (str(sheet.title) == str(content_of_key_sheet_file)):
       ws1 = wb1.worksheets[counter]
       print "Sheet selected"
       print sheet.title
   counter = counter + 1

ws2 = wb2.create_sheet(ws1.title)
print "Copying from the Excel file: " + path1
for row in ws1:
   for cell in row:
       if (cell.value != None):
          ws2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value

wb2.save(path2)
```

Answer (score 1):

install Pillow (just pip install Pillow, not needed import in your file)

then:

```
from openpyxl import drawing
```

.
.
.

```
img = drawing.image.Image('yourImg.png')
yourSheet.add_image(img, 'A2')
```

where A2 is your cell

Comment: `Pillow` is already installed. Still the image appears blank(placeholder) in the destination worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd been struggling with this for a bit as most of the libraries I typically use to manipulate xlsx files seemed to not want to support this. 
Fortunately, `.xlsx` is ooxml format.  Thus, all you need to do is unzip the `.xlsx` and locate the pictures in `xl/media/` of the directory you extracted your workbook to.

```
zip = ZipFile('yourWorkbook.xlsx')
zip.extractall()
```

Now you can insert them back into your new spreadsheet spreadsheet

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('test.jpg')
img.anchor(ws.cell('A1'))
ws.add_image(img)
wb.save('out.xlsx')
```